# Android actionbar with fragments orientation change retain values

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-orientation

i know there are many topics focussing this problem. but nothing fit yet.

so just a simple example:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab a = actionBar.newTab().setText("eins");
    ActionBar.Tab b = actionBar.newTab().setText("zwei");

    Fragment f1 = new MyFriendsListFragment();
    Fragment f2 = new SecondTabfrag();

    a.setTabListener(new myTabListener(f1, getApplicationContext()));
    b.setTabListener(new myTabListener(f2, getApplicationContext()));

    actionBar.addTab(a);
    actionBar.addTab(b);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());

}

}

class myTabListener implements TabListener {
Fragment fragment;
Context con;

myTabListener(Fragment f, Context c) {
    fragment = f;
    con = c;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

}
```

the first fragment contains just a non relevant list and my second tab looks like this

```
public class SecondTabfrag extends Fragment {
TextView t;
int i = 10;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondtabfragment, container, false);
    t = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.texfield);

    t.setText(i + "");

    Button b = (Button) V.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i=20;
        }
    });
    return V;
}
}
```

So the idea is: i got a button and when i press it my variable gets the value 20. if i reswitch my tab the new value is displayed. this works fine but if i change the orientation, the value is always 10. so the variable loses its value due to lifecycle of a fragment. so what can i do to save my value? i tried so many tutorials with getArguments and bundle and savedInstanceStance...but unfortunately i wasnt able to get things working as described :(

Regards
Hamzty

Comment: So a problem is that the onCreateView(...) is called 2 times after switching the tab - first round it is possible to load saved Values with onSavedInstance but they are overwritten by another instance of my fragment..